# How can i add two numbers with 12 bytes each-one?

Tags: assembly, x86, bigint, carryflag, extended-precision

I want to add two numbers that have 12 bytes and to store the result in a 16 bytes var. How can i do this?

```
section .data
    big_num1 dd 0x11111111, 0x22222222, 0x33333333
    big_num2 dd 0xffffffff, 0x22222222, 0x33333333
section .bss   
    result_4word resd 4
```

I think i can add the first 4 bytes number from number 1 with the other first 4 bytes from number 2 and so on.. but i don't know how to concatenate results in in my result variable.
How should i do the carry,if it's needed?
Is this solution the right one?

```
xor eax, eax
xor ebx, ebx
mov ecx, 3
loop1:
mov eax, dword[big_num1+4*(ecx-1)]
mov ebx, dword[big_num2+4*(ecx-1)]
mov [result_4word+4*(ecx-1)], eax
adc [result_4word+4*(ecx-1)], ebx
loop loop1
```

Comment: Read the entry for `adc` in the instruction set reference.

Comment: So...when i add from right to left should i verify if carry flag is on.

Comment: You don't have to verify anything. `adc` will do it for you. Add the lowest dwords with `add` use `adc` for the rest. Done.

Comment: For example : if i add big_num1+8 with big_num2+8 and carry flag is on, i should add 1 to the next add?(big_num +4)

Comment: Yes, but that is the explicit purpose of `adc` so you don't have to do it by hand.

Comment: Ah..ok i will try this

Comment: It looks ok but i don t know how to verify if it s the correct number

Comment: @Jester. You're idea don t work...idk why, but adc does the same thing like add. The carry must me made manually like i said before adc dont add 1 to the next for bytes..

Comment: It does work but you only have a carry from the final addition and you don't store that anywhere.

Comment: Look at compiler output for `uint64_t` on a 32-bit machine, and just do one more `adc` after that.

Comment: the size of  your operands and result are only limited by memory.  if you want a 1million bit number added to another 1 million bit number, super easy.  the first byte/word/dword whatever you choose you use add, for the remaining you use adc.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> big_num1 dd 0x11111111, 0x22222222, 0x33333333
> big_num2 dd 0xffffffff, 0x22222222, 0x33333333
> ```

### What numbers are defined here?

Because [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) is a little-endian architecture, the lowest part of a number is stored in memory at the lowest addresses. For *big_num1* the first defined dword (value is 0x11111111) is at the lowest address and thus is the lowest part of the number. In the normal number representation this is what goes at the right-handside.

```
big_num1 == 0x333333332222222211111111
big_num2 == 0x3333333322222222FFFFFFFF
```

### Adding big numbers

You add corresponding digits going from right to left, just like everybody has learned at school.

In the hexadecimal representation of these numbers there are 24 digits to consider. However since the architecture is 32-bit, we can nicely make 3 groups of 8 digits.

For the 1st group we simply use `ADD`:

```
mov     eax, [big_num1]           ;   0x11111111
add     eax, [big_num2]           ; + 0xFFFFFFFF <-- This produces a carry
mov     [result_4dword], eax      ;   0x00000000
```

For the 2nd group we use `ADC` to pick up a possible carry from the previous addition:

```
mov     eax, [big_num1 + 4]       ;   0x22222222
adc     eax, [big_num2 + 4]       ; + 0x22222222 + CF=1  <-- No new carry
mov     [result_4dword + 4], eax  ;   0x44444445
```

For the 3rd group we use `ADC` to pick up a possible carry from the previous addition:

```
mov     eax, [big_num1 + 8]       ;   0x33333333
adc     eax, [big_num2 + 8]       ; + 0x33333333 + CF=0  <-- No new carry
mov     [result_4dword + 8], eax  ;   0x66666666
```

### Turning this into a loop

Key here is that we can also use `ADC` for the 1st group **if we expressly clear the carry flag** beforehand:

```
clc
mov     eax, [big_num1]           ;   0x11111111
adc     eax, [big_num2]           ; + 0xFFFFFFFF + CF=0 <-- This produces a carry
mov     [result_4dword], eax      ;   0x00000000
```

Now we can write a loop with 3 iterations but we have **to be careful about not changing the carry flag inadvertently**. That's why I use `LEA` instead of `ADD` in order to advance the offset. `DEC` is also an instruction that does not destroy the carry flag. I've preferred the combo `DEC ECX` `JNZ ...` because it's better than `LOOP ...`:

```
    mov     ecx, 3
    xor     ebx, ebx              ; This additionally clears the carry flag
Again:
    mov     eax, [big_num1 + ebx]
    adc     eax, [big_num2 + ebx] ; Can produce a new carry flag
    mov     [result_4dword + ebx], eax
    lea     ebx, [ebx + 4]        ; This does not clobber the carry flag
    dec     ecx                   ; This does not clobber the carry flag
    jnz     Again
```

If after these 3 additions there's still a set carry, you'll have to write a **1** in the 4th dword of *result_4dword*, else you'll have to write a **0** here. Because *result_4dword* is in the .bss section, you should not count on any preset value like zero!

```
    setc    cl
    mov     [result_4dword + ebx], ecx  ; ECX=[0,1]
```

---

Please note that I've changed *result_4word* into *result_4**d**word*. Makes more sense...

Comment: Yes, `dec`/`jnz` is your best bet on Sandybridge-family, where partial-flag stalls aren't a problem.  On earlier Intel, like Nehalem and Core 2, you might want to save/restore flags or possibly loop with LEA / JECXZ / JMP (but that kinda sucks so you need to unroll to hide that cost).  [Problems with ADC/SBB and INC/DEC in tight loops on some CPUs](//stackoverflow.com/a/32087095).  It's really too bad that `loop` is slow on everything except recent AMD, because it's otherwise perfect for ADC loops

Answer (score 2):

Elementary school:

```
   1234
+  5678
========
```

Start filling it in

```
     1
   1234
+  5678
========
      2
```

4+8 = 12, so 2 carry the one.

In a computer you would:

add a = 4 + 8
adc b = 3 + 7
adc c = 2 + 6
adc d = 1 + 5

then dcba contain your result, it scales as wide as you want.  d,c,b,a can be 8 bit, 16 bit, 32 bit or 64 bit depending on the instruction set.  most have add and adc if they have flags, the ones that don't have flags then you can synthesize them in various ways that are not difficult at all... (break your operands into 16 bit quantities using 32 bit registers/memory do the 32 bit add now bit 16 is your carry out, add that into the next 16 bit chunk, takes some shifting and masking but it all works the same, since you probably have adc then you don't need to do any of that just do the trivial add, adc,adc, adc... until done.

If you clear the flag before you start you can use adc in a loop.

Now if your variables do not line up with the adder in the processor then you do have to synthesize it in some way.

Grade school math for the same problem, now you have to do the columns separately.

```
  4
+ 8
====
 12
```

and you have to manually mask and shift the result (12>>1) % 9 = 1 in base 10.

```
  1
  3
+ 7
====
 11
```

then

```
  1
  2
+ 6
====
  9
```

this one carries the zero:

```
  0
  1
+ 5
====
  6
```